# az sql server create active directory authentication

Tags: azure-sql-database

When creating an azure database using the azure-cli you cannot specify both an sql admin username and password and an sql ad admin username and password. It seems that you have to create the sql admin user and then when the server has been deployed login to the portal and specify an Active Directory Admin. Then you can connect the server as this Active Directory Admin and create other Active Directory Users or groups to have access to certain databases etc.

I am trying to automate the deployment tasks and would like the ability to specify an active directory sql admin at deployment and not have to connect to the portal and add this manually. Maybe add switch called --sqladminad and --sqladminpasswordad

If there is another way of not having to login to the portal and manually do this then please let me know. It might be I can use the rest api to do this but I could not see on the documentation how to accomplish this either.

Thanks

Comment: The azure-cli needed to setup the azure ad sql admin is not ready yet and should be available sometimes in June. Please contact again the MFAforSQLDB@microsoft.com alias around mid-June

Comment: Thanks very much